# How to work with Intellij Idea and Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I work on an SBT multi-module scala project.
I use Idea to edit code and an external terminal with sbt ~compile for compiling.

I'm not very happy with this workflow.

Is there a better way ?

There are options to configure at some places, the doc is not very clear, so how to configure that :

- in Build > Compiler > Scala compiler
- in Languages > Scala
- in Languages > Scala Compile Server

Do you configure some options on the scala compiler in idea ?

When and how do you compile (e.g. do you use make automatically in compiler settings) ?

Do you use idea or SBT for incrementality type

Answer (score 5):

You can import multi-project SBT projects into scala via

```
File -> Import Project...

SBT project
```

When importing, make sure you select `Use auto-import`. This will keep your IntelliJ environment in sync as you change your SBT build files.

Under 13, at least, you may have to go into

```
File -> Project Structure
```

and delete some extraneous projects it ends up creating (it seems to create a `project` and `project-build` for me).

Once set up, building in IntelliJ will build via SBT, i.e. it's the same behavior as building via `sbt compile`.